# Migrating from Eclipse to VSCode, what are alternatives to Open Implementation/References in Workspace

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm going to start developing in Javascript only, since Eclipse's js support isn't as good as it's java's, I did some search and found that VSCode seems to be on the cutting edge of javascript development nowadays. So, I'm migrating from Eclipse to VSCode, never liked Eclipse that much but I simply am way more effective with those two commands/hotkeys. So I'll give this example for those who aren't familiar:

foo.js

```
var foo = {
     doSomething: function(){
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}

module.exports = foo;
```

bar.js

```
var foo = require('./foo')

foo.doSomething();
```

Assuming this was in Eclipse and it was Java instead of Javascript: so in case I'm looking at bar.js, and I would like to know what the doSomething() is meant to do I would press F3 (Open Implementation) on the doSomething and it would go right to it's implementation on foo.js.

The other command, References in Workspace would be the other way around, if I'm at foo.js and I want to know in what places doSomething() is being called I would hit Ctrl+Shift+G, and in a small window it would show the exact line on bar.js (and any other files using it as well). Also, it's noteworthy to say that it wasn't just a simple search, it would not show any file that is calling a doSomething that isn't the doSomething declared in foo.js.

I've noticed that there's a Find All References in VSCode, but it only applies to the same file. 
There's also a Go To Declaration command, and it's actually useful, but it only applies to the same file. If I was on bar.js I could select foo on foo.doSomething(), use Go To Declaration and it would send me to the require statement. That's useful on large files but at the end of the day I'm still stuck at the require statement, and I can't quickly navigate to it's module.exports.

So yeah, I know that implementing these in javascript are way harder than at java, because of the classes/type structures and everything else. But these are my questions:

- Is there a way to achieve what I want natively in VSCode? Maybe there's a command that I am overlooking?
- Is there any extension that is able to achieve this. I remember trying one extension some time ago but it didn't work really well (it used to fail/crash). Maybe with TypeScript / ES6 it would be easier for a extension to work?
- If there isn't an exact alternative, what do you do to deal with these problems? How would you quickly go to a function's declaration that is on another file? Keeping in mind that the required file could be a lib on node_modules as well. And how would you find all the places that a certain function is being called, keeping in mind that there could be many other functions with the same name and in many files within your project.

I appreciate any help, and thanks for reading.

Comment: Just one question, have you tried https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Getting-Started?

Answer (score 1):

To enable this support across files you need to create a jsconfig.json file.

To quote the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript):

> JavaScript IntelliSense will work for single files immediately. If you
>   use the CommonJS module system that is used by Node.js, then you get
>   IntelliSense across your modules immediately.
>
> There are two more steps to configure IntelliSense across all the
>   files in your workspace and external modules:
>
> Create a jsconfig.json file to indicate a JavaScript project. Install
>   TypeScript Definition files (typings) for external libraries.

The documentation has more information about different settings, but simply creating a file named `jsconfig.json` in your project root should be sufficient to get started:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

If you want more information into the workings of the javascript language service that vscode is using, you can look at the [Salsa](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Salsa) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to achieve what I want natively in VSCode? Maybe
>   there's a command that I am overlooking?

Yes, I think what you want is built-in.   Try pressing **F12** (Go To Definition) with the cursor on the symbol you are looking for...   Sometimes I have to press it twice for things `import`ed in TypeScript, but it works well for me.

This doesn't seem to require a `jsconfig.json`, it worked for me with just the two files you mentioned in otherwise-empty directory.   I could imagine however that incorrect settings in a config file might block it.

You can change the key-bindings if you want using the *Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts* command.  Unfortunately I think there isn't (yet) a library of key-bindings for emulation of other IDEs.